# How do i add custom icon on expo push notification?

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

i followed the documentation guide on expo [link](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/https://) , yet it doesn't work ,the icon is not displayed in the push notification

```
    {
  "expo": {
  
......
    "android": {
      "package": "com.moohub.safenaija",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "......."
      }
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-notifications",
      {
        "icon": "./assets/safe.png",
        "color": "#000000'",
        "iosDisplayInForeground": true,
        "androidMode": "default",
        "androidCollapsedTitle": "Updates from SafeNaija"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

i would appreciate if someone can help solve this issue

Comment: The "link" generated a 404 HTTP status code - not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people who might have come across this issue, i solved it by using a logo with monochrome color and a transparent background,in production it all works well and displays the standard logo